# Yii2 change breadcrumb url

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

There are two user types in my admin application. If an admin is logged in, there should be a param in each url like this:

```
Home>>Property>> view property

Current url : www.example.com/property/index
Desired Url : www.example.com/property/index?agentid=5
```

How can I achieve this?

This param value will be dynamic and only for admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top of your view file, (I consider `view.php`) You can use `User::can()` function to [check for some admin/other permissions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user#can()-detail), and look at this example code to add param to link:

```
if (Yii::$app->user->can('admin')) {
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Property', 'url' => ['index', 'agentid' => 5]];
} else {
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Property', 'url' => ['index']];
}
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

It adds `agentid=5` param if user has `admin` permission, and do not otherwise